# Grails "Unparseable Date" Error

Tags: date, grails, groovy, type-conversion, date-formatting

I've seen some Unparseable Date errors on here before, but mine doesn't seem to make any sense. I'm uploading a CSV file, which is going to be displayed in a table on a webpage (that much I know and is easy) and I'm trying to find a way to take the date in a cell and convert it from it's native string format to a date.

Here's the code:

```
        def line = f.inputStream.toCsvReader(['skipLines':1]).eachLine{fields ->
        List list = new List()
        list.item = fields[0].trim()
        String checkedOut = fields[1].trim()
        String returned = fields[2].trim()
        Date c = Date.parse('E MM/dd/yy', checkedOut)
        Date r = Date.parse('E MM/dd/yy', returned)
        list.lastCheckedOut = c
        list.lastReturned = r
        list.checkedOutBy = fields[4].trim()
        list.save flush: true
        return
    }
```

Here's the stacktrace

```
Error 2015-08-21 16:13:38,936 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ParseException occurred when processing request: [POST] /inventory/list/upload - parameters:
upload: Upload
Unparseable date: "9/22/94". Stacktrace follows:
Message: Unparseable date: "9/22/94"
    Line | Method
->>  357 | parse     in java.text.DateFormat
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     27 | doCall    in org.ListController$_upload_closure1$$EPM22klU
|     34 | eachLine  in org.grails.plugins.csv.CSVReaderUtils
|    126 | doCall    in CsvGrailsPlugin$_closure4$_closure8
|     22 | upload .  in org.ListController$$EPM22klU
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

The date held in "fields[1]" is 9/22/94, I'm not entirely sure what the issue here is, everything I've read seems to show that this should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your domain:

```
@BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
 Date lastCheckedOut
```

And set the property this way:

```
list.lastCheckedOut = Date.parse('E MM/dd/yy', checkedOut).format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Edit: you will need to do the following import into your domain class:

```
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the 'E' it will parse. It's not being provided in the date Strings.

```
Date c = Date.parse('MM/dd/yy', checkedOut)
Date r = Date.parse('MM/dd/yy', returned)
```

## Example

```
assert Date.parse('MM/dd/yy', "9/22/94").toString() == 'Thu Sep 22 00:00:00 EDT 1994'
```